# How to get a list of defined tests in sbt project in sbt 0.12?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

How to get a list of test cases (fully qualified names) under current project?

The environment is Scala 2.10.2, Sbt 0.12.3 and scalatest 1.9.1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`(definedTests in Test)` returns `sbt.TestDefinition`.

```
val printTests = taskKey[Unit]("something")

printTests := {
  val tests = (definedTests in Test).value
  tests map { t =>
    println(t.name)
  }
}
```

The above is in sbt 0.13 syntax, but the idea should be same in sbt 0.12.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am not sure how to use it.  Can I use this from the SBT command prompt or does it need to be in a configuration file?  Personally, I would like the former.